# How to escape all characters with special meaning in Regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I just stumbled upon the following which I can't quite get my head around. When you create a new Regexp in Ruby like so:

```
Regexp.new('http://www.example.com')
```

it will output the following:

```
/http:\/\/www.example.com/
```

which is correct, but doesn't escape the `.`; this means it basically allows for any character to be on that place. Getting around this can be achieved by doing:

```
Regexp.new(Regexp.escape('http://www.example.com'))
# => /http:\/\/www\.example\.com/
```

This solution looks a little odd though, so maybe there is a better one?

Comment: How do you use the regex? Depending on your usage, there may be a different, simpler solution that will make the escaping obsolete. For example, you might not even need a regex and can perform a direct matching on the string.

Comment: Regexp.new should not escape regexp special characters.  Otherwise how would you say something like `/^.{4}$/`.  Regexp.escape does escape regexp special characters, ie. it produces the regexp string that would match the literal content of the input string.  So `Regexp.new(Regexp.escape...` is the straight forward solution.

Answer (score 8):

You can do:

```
Regexp.escape('http://www.example.com')
```

That will return the fully escaped string

Comment: @Severin Of course it is, you have an escaped \ i.e. \\. Try putting a `puts` before it...

Comment: It doesn't need to - / isn't a special character. You need to escape writing a regex literal using / as the delimiter but that's so that ruby can find the start/end of your literal

Comment: Yes, but what I need is this: /http:\/\/www\.example\.com/

Comment: What not a different delimiter like `~` or `@`? Using a `/` for a file tree (like URL) is ugly to look at. `~http://www\.example\.com~` is more clear

Comment: @Severin this is the correct solution. You just need to build a regex from it, i.e. `Regexp.new(Regexp.escape('http://www.example.com'))` will produce `/http:\/\/www\.example\.com/`

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, if you just need to check whether a given text contains the specified url you can use `String#include?`, and drop the regex altogether. Bearing in mind that Ruby will just do simple string comparisons, this should also be faster.

```
# before
if text =~ Regexp.new(Regexp.escape('http://www.example.com'))
  ...
end

# after
if text.include?('http://www.example.com')
  ...
end
```

Comment: The point is that I don't know what the strings are going to contain. It might as well be ['something','someother'], in which case I want it to return 'some'.

Comment: @Severin please post example code in your original question so we can find the best solution.